# Update Facebook fanpage status from Twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter, synchronization

I would update the status of a couple of Facebook fanpages through their Twitter accounts, but can not find a way to synchronize directly (without using a specific Twitter client to write the updates). The Twitter application for Facebook will not work because it only allows you to synchronize an account.

Comment: You will either have to control it yourself with a script that watches your twitter rss feed or You will have to use the Involver application which throttles for unpaid services. http://www.involver.com/applications/free/

Comment: Try http://restatus.me . Also your statuses will be sharable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution: http://apps.facebook.com/smarttwitterpages/
With this app, you can set a twitter account for each fanpage that you have

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selective Tweets](http://www.facebook.com/selectivetwitter) to do this.

Once setup you simply end your Tweets with `#fb` and they will be picked up and displayed on your Facebook profile.

EDIT:

I should say that this works with Fan Pages also.

Comment: The OP is asking about fan pages not profile pages.

Comment: @ChrisF - This works with Fan Pages as well. I have updated my answer to clarify.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, I had tried, but I hate having to add the hashtag #fb

Comment: i love selective tweets :D