# Blank page at http://apps.facebook.com/twitter/

Tags: facebook, twitter

The Twitter app is showing in my Facebook profile, so I think it's installed, but when I go here: http://apps.facebook.com/twitter/ -- I just get a blank page.

According to help videos I've watched, when I go there, there should be the ability to specify which of my Facebook pages my tweets should be published on.

I'd like to make my tweets appear on my page -- not my personal page -- my business page.

Why is the http://apps.facebook.com/twitter/ page blank? How do I get this app to function?

Comment: Related - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10054/update-facebook-fanpage-status-from-twitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delete/uninstall the application, remove the permissions and try again.

I wish I could tell you the exact problem with the application but I have not figured it out. Facebook and Twitter do not share information well so there are bugs that have not been fixed over the past few months.